# wget and curl switch default to background task

Tags: bash, wget, curl

When I use wget and curl from bash, it automatically switches to a background task by default, without me having provided the required arguments.  This is making it hard to use these commands in scripts.  Example:

```
22:32 $ curl -L -o firefox.tar.bz2 https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US  && echo done
[1] 135093
[2] 135094
done
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0[2]+  Done                    os=linux64
✔ /tmp
100   132  100   132    0     0    643      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   640
100 52.7M  100 52.7M    0     0  10.3M      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 11.1M

[1]+  Done                    curl -L -o firefox.tar.bz2 https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest
22:45 $ curl --version
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.13
```

wget does the same thing, and while both programs have an option to tell it to immediately switch to the background, I'm not providing it, and this is breaking a script I'm writing. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: The string you intended to be the URL contains **ampersand `&` which is shell syntax** for "run the left hand side in background and the right hand side in parellel"; the right hand side consists of assignments that do no output, and an `echo` command. If you want a string containing ampersand to be an argument to a program (here the URL), it must be quoted with backslash (can't show properly in Stack comment), doublequotes `" "` or singlequotes `' '`.

Comment: This is the answer. Seems obvious now.